# Prevent user to do any action on dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My page has two jquery dialogs. There is no issue if both open in different time. The issue only comes when two dialog opens together. In my case first dialog opens by user action and second dialog open by system(this dialog will trigger when session timeout happened). Now first open by user and immediately  second dialog opened now I need restrict user to click anything on dialog 1. Basically we should restrict user to do any action dialog one.

I tried with *resizable: false, draggable: false* But these not helped. Is there any way to fix this issue.

Dialog 1

```
$('.status-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons: [{
                text: yes,
                click: fun1
            },
            {
                text: no,
                click: fun2

            }]
        });
```

Dialog 2

```
$('body').append('<div title="Timeout" id="timeout-dialog">' expired </div>');
        $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            open: function () { $(".ui-dialog").hide(); },
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have your code to close all other dialogs right before the system triggers one for itself? You can certainly add this condition somewhere between your codes where the dialog will be triggered system-wise.

Comment: Is there any jquery utility method to close all other dialog before dialog 2 opens?

Comment: not so sure about that. But you can give them all a class name. And $('.classname').dialog('close'); should do the trick.

Comment: Tried with below sytax non of them closed the dialog. 1) $('.status-dialog').dialog('close'); 2)  $('.status-dialog').dialog().dialog("close");
       3) jQuery(".status-dialog").dialog('close');

Comment: Seems like because the dialog is initialized with id, but we are trying to close with class selector which may not work. But it is supposed to IMO. Maybe you can try to close each of the class item instead of the entire class. $.each('.status-dialog', function(){ $(this).dialog('close') });

Comment: $.each('.status-dialog', function(){ $(this).dialog('close') }); worked for me

Comment: glad that it helped!